# DHIS 2 Regarding Data Entry Forms

Tags: dhis-2

DHIS 2 Open Source Project

I am using DHIS-2 Software for our Malaria MIS System For Analysis and maintain performances regarding malaria information and management system.

**Problem I Face using DHIS-2 is That :**

I have to Create a data set that contain some dynamic elements (input fields) which may generate on run time. There max limit is not defined. Its Based on Data that to be entered.
How I manage it in DHIS-2 Data entry Forms Creation ? Or any other feature of dhis-2 that solve that issue ?

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Omer. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but you can not dynamically create new data elements during data entry. The way the data set model works, is that it's a fixed set of data elements. If you are talking about hiding and showing existing fields, that is not supported by Data Entry, but you could create your own app to replicate the behaviour